# TypeScript query property does not exist

Tags: typescript, graphql

I try to add Query types on GraphQL query using TypeScript, but i don't understand why TS return me this error :

`Property 'userMe' does not exist on type 'Query | null'.`

My Query :

```
const { userMe }: Query | null = cache.readQuery({
  query: ME,
});
```

And my types :

```
export type Query = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  files?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<UploadFile>>>;
  me?: Maybe<UsersPermissionsMe>;
  userMe?: Maybe<CustomUsersPermissionsMe>;
};
```

`userMe` is present, but not required. I don't understand why TS cry about this :D I use TS v3.7.5.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the return value of `cache.readQuery()` may be `null`. Its return type is `Query | null` by the look of the error message. Your code will throw an exception if it is null.

Instead of:

```
const { userMe }: Query | null = cache.readQuery({
  query: ME,
});
```

You need to do:

```
const query = cache.readQuery({
  query: ME,
});
const userMe = query && query.userMe ? query.userMe: undefined
```

You need to deal with the fact that the query result may be null, and that the `userMe` may be `undefined` on a non-null query.

At a high-level, TypeScript is forcing you to write code that deals with the fact that things may be `null` or `undefined` at runtime. Your type signature models two scenarios where that may be the case (null Query result, and undefined field on non-null Query).

How you handle that in your code depends on how your program should behave in that situation.

At the very least you do something like:

```
if (userMe !=== undefined) {
  // TS now knows that in here userMe is Maybe<CustomUsersPermissionsMe>
}
```

You have to guard against undefined because it is nullable on the `Query` object itself. And then it is a `Maybe`, so you have a bunch of guards to write.

Comment: Thank you Josh, it's okay i've understand my problem :) I've updated my code with your response, and it work nice : `const userMe = query?.userMe;`

Comment: Mmm nop for me, using `react-apollo` 3.1.3

Comment: Now I get `Object is of type 'unknown'.` 